# How can I call a function to wich I pass some captured value in reg_replace in second parameter of reg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace a link with anchor tag and use substring function on the part that follows http://;
This is what I did but it is not producing what I want

```
$text =  preg_replace( '#(http://([a-z0-9._/-\?&=])+)#' , '<a href="$1">' . substring(0,30,'$2') .'</a>',$text) ;
```

I would like  to use substring on $2 to reduce the text to at least to 30 characters if there are more so that $textreturned has an anchor tag with a text in `<a>` tag that is 30 characters long.

Comment: Post your possible inputs with expected outputs. But a quick fix you need to take care about `quotes` within your `replace`. Try updating `'<a href="$1">' . substring(0,30,'$2') .'</a>'` into `"<a href='$1'>" . substring(0,30,"$2") ."</a>"`

Comment: You just need to use preg_replace_callback.